# How to make WinCVS show only Unmodified files

Tags: filtering, cvs, wincvs

I'm using WinCvs 2.0.0.2 (Build 2).

How can I make it filter, to show only files that are:

- known to CVS
- not modified

### Things I've tried

#### Filters

I've looked at all the filters at the top in the toolbar, and I can't see how any combination of these could show only unchanged files:

- Show All Commitable Files Only
- Show Changed Files Only
- Show Added Files Only
- Show Removed Files Only
- Show Conflict Files Only
- Show Missing Only
- Hide Any Missing
- Show Unknown Only
- Hide Amy Unknown
- Show Any Ignored

#### Filter Bar

I've also tried enabling the Filter Bar, to filter on the value in the State column.

I had thought this was the most promising approach, but the problem is that I can't work out how to make this filter to only show rows where the State value is *empty*.

The help in WinCvs's "Select State Filter" dialog is rather content-free:

> **Filter Selection dialog box**
>
> The dialog options allow you to select the filter value from any of the previously used ones.

I've googled for tips on the Filter Bar, and not spotted any useful tips on how to use this to *exclude* values. I've read the [CvsGui FAQ](http://cvsgui.sourceforge.net/newfaq.htm), and can't see any explanation of more advanced use of the Filter Bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is really simple: No, this not possible.
This: http://cvsgui.sourceforge.net/newfaq.htm#filters_howto is really all there is.

What is your use case, though?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I honestly can't remember what my use-case was, but as we moved to Mercurial 2.5 weeks ago, I'm not worried any more :-)

Comment: filter will list the files in the end folder like what all modified and not modified . But these filters will not show all the modified files in root folder.

Answer (score 0):

This Facility is not available in WINCVS. It is available only in eclipse plugin.